# Tesseract read an image online?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Im about to start working with tesseract, tess4j to be exact, and im going through the api docs. I havent come across any way to read from a webpage.

Basically the program opens a webpage that is just an image. I want tess4j to read the image from the page and convert it to words. If tess4j cant do this is there any other java ocrs that would be helpful, preferably without downloading the image?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading and downloading are synonymous. If you are looking into reading an image from a web-page without opening it in a web-page, I would suggest looking into the "curl" command and it's equivalent in Java. After getting the image with the aforementioned command, it can then be parsed with Tesseract.

Comment: When I click a link, the webpage has a picture on it. I wanna pass this picture to tesseract for it to try and convert it to words. Like the picture on this page for example (I realize it doesnt have any words in it) https://twitter.com/Amareisreal/status/337725110901424129/photo/1

Comment: When you left click on this image you are able to "Copy image URL". In this case, the URL is https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BK_XMvNCQAAYp0Z.jpg:large which you can confirm by copying and pasting the link into your browser. This is the URL you want to "curl" it into your program. After a quick Google, I found that equivalent in Java is called the HTTPClient.

Comment: After you have used HTTPClient to assign the image to a variable, you can pass it to Tesseract. Please let me know if you need further conceptual clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
String imageURL = "<Remote URL of image>";
String result = "";
URL url = new URL(imageURL);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath("<your tessdata path>");
result = instance.doOCR(img);
```